# awk with variable in python

Tags: python, awk

Lets say I have this command in python

```
response = requests.get('https://host/api/v13/clusters/cluster/services/impalaQueries', verify=false, auth=('user', pass))
```

Which has sample data like this:

```
 "queryId" : "8f46683f7c2c8fee:6504618f00000000",
"queryState" : "FINISHED",
"rowsProduced" : null,
 etc....
```

How can I use awk with my response variable? For example awk -F':' '/queryId/

Comment: Why would you use awk for this and not python ?

Comment: Especially if the output is JSON (which it looks like) -- Python's `json` module will parse it much more accurately than you can do with awk. And `requests` can return the data as a native Python data structure directly.

Comment: Good question. I will be working with a lot more data than this in the python script where I will be using this awk output in different loops etc,..

Comment: If you're going to be working with a lot of data, it's probably worth learning to use Python to process it natively.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy are you recommending not using awk within my script and figuring out other ways to extract the data I need from that variable? I will need to extract lines that are greater than certain number and i already know how to do it with awk just not with python variable

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I recommend. What you need may be as simple as `requests.get('https://host/api/v13/clusters/cluster/services/impalaQueries', verify=false, auth=('user', pass)).json()['queryId']`

Comment: Can anyone advise on the downvote so I can improve myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First: If your data is JSON (and in most cases where it isn't), *don't.*

awk can't parse JSON accurately -- that's the whole reason specialized tools like `jsawk` were written as alternatives. Similarly, Python comes with a compliant CSV parser, *several* compliant XML parsers, and other tools that are going to do a better job of handling standardized formats than anything hand-rolled in `awk`.

For your specific use case, the `requests` module will even invoke Python's JSON parser for you if you ask:

```
queryId = requests.get('https://host/api/v13/clusters/cluster/services/impalaQueries',
                       verify=false, auth=('user', pass)).json()['queryId']
```

---

#### Second: If you *really* want to invoke `awk`, use the `subprocess` module.

```
response = '''
ignore this line
queryId foo
ignore this line also
'''

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['awk', '-F:', '/queryId/'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
(output, _) = p.communicate(response)

print(output)
```

...properly emits only:

```
queryId foo
```

Comment: CSV or JSON or any format : don't use awk within python unless you are sure that you can take benefits from this

Comment: @CorentinLimier thank you, what do you recommend using instead of awk?

Comment: I recommend Python

Comment: @user3508766, I actually don't recommend jsawk personally either -- the command-line tool I prefer for working with JSON from shell is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), but I wouldn't (and don't) use it from Python -- no reason to mix two languages when Python alone can do everything.